# Minimum amount of tiles needed to cover points on a line

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Minimum amount of tiles needed to cover points on a line

Suppose we have n points evenly spaced on a line, say 1 length unit apart. Every point has a tile associated with it, which has a length to the left and a length to the right, in other words it can cover some amount of points to its left and another to its right. What is an algorithm to determine the minimum number of tiles needed to cover all the points (the tiles are allowed to overlap)?

I think there's a greedy approach such as if we start at point 1, pick the tile which covers most points to the right, and then repeat on the next point not covered until we've covered every point but i'm having some trouble convincing myself that this will always yield an optimal solution. Maybe there is a similar problem?

One example of size 10 https://imgur.com/a/7vHKTLe.

[image: example]

The vertical lines show which point the tile is associated with, and to the left of its line it has length to the left, dito to the right. Here the minimum tiles needed would be 3, since we can pick tile 1, 5 and 8.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Spektre I added an image with a sample solution. The problem is 1D.

Comment: The algorithm you described is the brute force O(n^2) algorithm. The solution will be optimal. A greedy algorithm would be O(n), choosing any tile that makes progress. In your example, a greedy algorithm would choose tiles 1,3,5,7,8.

Comment: In the example, the start point of the tiles is monotonically increasing. Likewise for the end point of the tiles. If that's a guaranteed feature of the problem, then there may be an optimal O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @Spektre A slightly different interpretation of the problem is that **the tiles aren't movable**. The tile sizes and positions are an input to the algorithm, and the challenge is to find "the minimum number of tiles needed to cover all the points".

Comment: @user3386109 yes, the tiles arent movable

Comment: @GroggerVving Is it guaranteed that the start point of the tiles is monotonically increasing?

Comment: @user3386109 No i dont think so, in my above example tile 3's starting point could be the first point for instance

Comment: @GroggerVving That's actually still monotonic. Could tile 4 start at the first point, without changing tile 3, so that tile 4 starts before tile 3?

Comment: @user3386109 yes tile t_i+1 could have an earlier start point than t_i

Comment: @GroggerVving  Ok, got it. I'd begin by sorting the list of tiles by start point. Then I think one pass through the list of tiles is enough to find the answer. So the time is O(NlogN).

Comment: made update in my answer... You still did not respond: what is target number of points and tiles ? are they always the same? what is the target time? what computing HW?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you could start with:

1. **use binary representation**

   For small number of tiles is possible to use binary representation of the solution and all the underlying states while fitting into single unsigned integer (or few of them). This will get rid of nested `for` loops leading to Brute force complexity `O(tiles*(2^tiles))` with small constant time.
2. **sort tiles by position**
3. **use bit mask LUT of points coverage for each tile**

   simply precompute which points are covered by each tile and store the result as single unsigned integer per tile. This will allow very fast checking of solution using simple bitwise OR operator.
4. **remove tiles fully covered by other tile**

   this will lower the number of tiles needed to check which is significant speed up.
5. **divide the problem to smaller ones**

   simply by solve by brute force (for example every 16 points). This might cause some abundant tiles on joints to be selected.

Here small C++/VCL example (55 points/tiles just ignore the VCL stuff, `txtlog` and time measurement `tbeg,tend,tstr`):

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include "str.h"
#include "performance.h"
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #define _generate_input
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _generate_input
// hardcoded sample input
int tile[][3]=  // tiles: position,start point,end point
    {
    0,0,2,
    1,0,2,
    2,1,4,
    3,2,4,
    4,2,6,
    5,3,6,
    6,4,7,
    7,5,9,
    8,6,9,
    9,7,9,
    };
const int _tiles=sizeof(tile)/sizeof(tile[0]);  // original number of tiles
#else
const int _tiles=55;        // original number of tiles
      int tile[_tiles][3];  // tiles: position,start point,end point
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      int tiles=_tiles;     // actual number of tiles
const int points=_tiles;    // number of points

const int T_bits=64; typedef unsigned __int64 T;

T cov[_tiles];              // point coverage per tile LUT
T sol0=0;                   // solution
T sol1=0;                   // solution
AnsiString txtlog="";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void tile_swap(int i,int j)
    {
    int a;
    a=tile[i][0]; tile[i][0]=tile[j][0]; tile[j][0]=a;
    a=tile[i][1]; tile[i][1]=tile[j][1]; tile[j][1]=a;
    a=tile[i][2]; tile[i][2]=tile[j][2]; tile[j][2]=a;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void generate() // generate input
    {
    int i,x;
    RandSeed=0x08123456;
    for (i=0;i<tiles;i++)
        {
                                                  tile[i][0]=i;
        x=i-Random(5); if (x<      0) x=       0; tile[i][1]=x;
        x=i+Random(5); if (x>=points) x=points-1; tile[i][2]=x;
        }
    for (i=0;i<tiles;i++) tile_swap(i,Random(tiles));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void precompute()
    {
    tbeg(); txtlog+="precompute: ";
    T jm;
    int i,j,a,del[_tiles];
    // bubble sort tiles by position O(n^2)
    for (j=tiles,a=1;a;j--)             // loop until no swap occurs
     for (a=0,i=1;i<j;i++)              // proces unsorted part of array
      if (tile[i-1][0]>tile[i][0])      // condition if swap needed
       { tile_swap(i,i-1); a=1; }       // swap and allow to process array again
    // mark tiles fully inside another tile O(n^2)
    for (i=0;i<tiles;i++) del[i]=0;
    for (i=0;i<tiles;i++) if (!del[i])
     for (j=i+1;j<tiles;j++) if (!del[j])
        {
        if (tile[j][1]>=tile[i][1])     // tile[j] is fully inside tile[i]
         if (tile[j][2]<=tile[i][2])
         { del[j]=1; continue; }
        if (tile[i][1]>=tile[j][1])     // tile[i] is fully inside tile[j]
         if (tile[i][2]<=tile[j][2])
          { del[i]=1; break; }
        }
    // delete marked tiles O(n)
    for (i=0,j=0;i<tiles;i++)
     if (!del[i])
        {
        tile[j][0]=tile[i][0];
        tile[j][1]=tile[i][1];
        tile[j][2]=tile[i][2];
        j++;
        } tiles=j;
    for (;j<_tiles;j++)
        {
        tile[j][0]=-1;
        tile[j][1]=-1;
        tile[j][2]=-1;
        }
    // compute point coverage of tiles LUT
    for (i=0;i<tiles;i++)
     for (cov[i]=0,j=tile[i][1],jm=1,jm<<=j;j<=tile[i][2];j++,jm<<=1)
      cov[i]|=jm;
    for (;i<_tiles;i++) cov[i]=0;
    tend(); txtlog+=tstr()+"\r\n";
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
T solve_brute_force()
    {
    tbeg(); txtlog+="     brute: ";
    int t,n0,n;
    T cm,s0,s,tm,pm,tmax,pmax;
    tmax=0; tmax--; tmax>>=T_bits-tiles;
    pmax=0; pmax--; pmax>>=T_bits-points;
    // brute force all combinations
    s0=0; n0=tiles+1;
    for (s=0;s<=tmax;s++)
        {
        // cm = coverage mask, n = numbner of used tiles
        for (cm=0,n=0,t=0,tm=1;t<tiles;t++,tm<<=1)
         if ((s&tm)!=0){ cm|=cov[t]; n++; }
        // skip wrong solutions
         if (cm!=pmax) continue;
        // remember best solution
        if (n0>n){ s0=s; n0=n; }
        }
    tend(); txtlog+=tstr()+AnsiString().sprintf(" N=%i\r\n",n0);
    return s0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
T solve_brute_force(int p0,int p1)
    {
    int t,t0,t1,n0,n;
    T cm,s0,s,tm,tm0,pm,tmax,pmax;
    tmax=0; tmax--; tmax>>=T_bits-tiles;
    pmax=0; pmax--; pmax>>=T_bits-(p1-p0); pmax<<=p0;

    // t0 = first tile covering part of <p0,p1>
    for (t0=      0;t0<tiles;t0++) if (tile[t0][2]>=p0) break;
    // t1 = last tile covering part of <p0,p1>
    for (t1=tiles-1;t1>   t0;t1--) if (tile[t1][1]<=p1) break;
    tm0=1; tm0<<=t0;
    tmax=1; tmax<<=(t1-t0+1); tmax--; tmax<<=t0;

    // brute force all combinations
    s0=0; n0=tiles+1;
    for (s=tm0;s<=tmax;s+=tm0)
        {
        // cm = coverage mask, n = numbner of used tiles
        for (cm=0,n=0,t=0,tm=1;t<tiles;t++,tm<<=1)
         if ((s&tm)!=0){ cm|=cov[t]; n++; }
        // skip wrong solutions
         if ((cm&pmax)!=pmax) continue;
        // remember best solution
        if (n0>n){ s0=s; n0=n; }
        }
    return s0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int solve_fast()
    {
    tbeg(); txtlog+="      fast: ";
    int t,p0,p1,dp=16,n=0;
    T s,ss;

    for (s=0,p0=0;p0<points;p0+=dp)
        {
        p1=p0+dp; if (p1>=points) p1=points-1;
        s|=solve_brute_force(p0,p1);
        }
        
    for (n=0,ss=s;ss;ss>>=1) if ((ss&1)!=0) n++;

    tend(); txtlog+=tstr()+AnsiString().sprintf(" N=%i\r\n",n);
    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    int i,x,y,d=xs/(points+1),r=(d*10)/25,r2=r>>1;
    unsigned int m;

    // render points
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    for (x=d,y=d,i=0;i<points;i++,x+=d) bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);

    // render tiles
    for (m=1,y=d+d,i=0;i<tiles;i++,m<<=1,y+=r,y=(y>ys-d)?d+d:y)
        {
        if ((sol0&m)!=0) bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clYellow;
        else             bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clDkGray;
        x=d+(d*tile[i][0]);
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y-r2);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y+r2);
        x=d+(d*tile[i][1]);
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        x=d+(d*tile[i][2]);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }

    for (m=1,y=d+d,i=0;i<tiles;i++,m<<=1,y+=r,y=(y>ys-d)?d+d:y)
        {
        y+=2;
        if ((sol1&m)!=0) bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
        else             bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clDkGray;
        x=d+(d*tile[i][0]);
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y-r2);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y+r2);
        x=d+(d*tile[i][1]);
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        x=d+(d*tile[i][2]);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        y-=2;
        }

    AnsiString s;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=clSilver;
    for (x=d,y=ys2,i=1;i<=txtlog.Length();y+=16)
        {
        s=str_load_lin(txtlog,i,true);
        bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(x,y,s);
        }
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;


    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Charset=OEM_CHARSET;
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Name="System";
    bmp->Canvas->Font->Pitch=fpFixed;
    pyx=NULL;

    #ifdef _generate_input
    generate();
    #endif

    precompute();
    sol0=solve_brute_force();
    sol1=solve_fast();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;  xs2=xs>>1;
    ys=ClientHeight; ys2=ys>>1;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    if (pyx) delete pyx;
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(int*) bmp->ScanLine[y];
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and preview:

[image: preview 55]

Yellow lines are brute force and aqua lines are fast solution tiles.

The `#define _generate_input` just chose between auto generated and your hardcoded input. as you can see fast version is really fast (you can play with number of points per chunk `dp`). The `T` variable should be unsigned int with enough bits to hold all the point/tiles ...

Here (old) preview for brute force and your input:

[image: preview 10]

Now to remedy the joints I would chose the dp to be bigger than max tile size. And probably do two solutions shifted by dp/2 points:

```
XXXX XXXX XXXX  ... XXXX XXXX

YY YYYY YYYY YYYY ... YYYY YY
```

then just check the differences between solutions and prefer solution with less set bits.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove optimality for the greedy procedure, "for each point yet to be covered, pick the tile that covers it and the most points to the right," by contradiction.

Clearly, we must cover the "point yet to be covered," call it `p`. Call the rightmost point we can reach with a tile from here `r`, and the tile that reaches it `A`. Now assume the optimal sequence would have a tile `B` that doesn't reach as far to the right, followed by some tile `C`. So the next "point yet to be covered" would be left of `r`, call it `r0`.

```
         A
  -----------------
  p         r0     r
------------  ------------
      B           C
```

So we have used `B` and a tile `C` when we could have used `A` and `C` with the same coverage. Therefore `A` is part of an optimal sequence.

[edit in by Spektre] I meant (simplified) situation like this:

```
         A
 p-----------------r------- 
                       -----------
                            -----------------------------
------------r0----------------------------------------
      B                             C
```

[Response by this answer's author] for the latter case, the greedy procedure would choose A for p, and C for r.

Comment: maybe its just my bad English or that I have not my morning tea yet, but how is this a proof of optimality?  what if choosing `C` tile will lead to less tiles later after your `r`  (when C will cover more tiles latter on)? Removing `B` tile can be done by simply removing all fully covered tiles by single tile (like I did in my answer). With such filter prior to your algo this could be optimal but my intuition is still not fully sure of it ... would be good to compare brute force with yours on some generated inputs just to be "sure" first

Comment: @Spektre sorry the information about tile C was not clear -- it's defined as part of an assumed optimal sequence. (I updated the answer.)

Comment: @Spektre we can also prove by induction. Clearly,  for the starting (leftmost) point, since tiles can overlap (per the problem description), the leftmost tile can be chosen to cover the most points to the right. Now repeat this process starting on the next point yet to be covered.

Comment: I edited in the situation of what I meant to and of your answer (would be unreadable as comment) ... choosing tile A according to your algo might lead to more tiles latter by skiping C  (unless some preprocessing is done first)

Comment: @Spektre the greedy algorithm I attempted to prove would not skip C. I edited into my answer a response :)